# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type AlgorithmDialog has been deleted - Custom Processing Script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

This is my first real project for QGIS so I'm completely in the dark for the best practices. I'm working on a custom processing script within QGIS. Simply put the script uses the 'extract by location' on a bunch of shape files (routes in this case) (about 150 routes) puts them into a 'Cache' on a per route basis which is then moved into a per county schedule.

The problem I'm running into is that at the end of the script QGIS throws an error.
The script itself runs and works exactly as expected. A weird behaviour I've noticed is that the feedbox window closes midway through the script yet no where in my script am I closing it. From what I can tell this is what the error is referring to.

> The {Variable} ELECTRICAL and STRUCTURAL are two point layers within my QGIS project with attached attributes such as Asset type, Latitude, Longitude etc

Feedback Window closing after so many iterations:
[image]

QGIS Error:

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type AlgorithmDialog has been deleted 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS 
3.30.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmDialog.py", line 337, in 
runAlgorithm
on_complete(ok, results)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS 
3.30.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmDialog.py", line 286, in 
on_complete
self.tr(elapsed_time(start_time, 'Execution completed in')))
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS 
3.30.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmDialog.py", line 236, in 
elapsed_time
str_hours = [self.tr("hour"), self.tr("hours")][hours > 1]
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type AlgorithmDialog has been deleted

Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit 
(AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.30.2-'s-Hertogenbosch 's-Hertogenbosch, 0992b533
```

[image]

Custom Processing Script:
https://pastebin.com/yELBFzVx

Again I'd like to confirm that the schedule does work exactly as expected with all routes included and all information expected.